# How to explain not working "Tee-Object" when "Select-Object -First" occurs

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, pipeline, powershell-5.0

With the following code, `$t` equals `@(1,2)`.

```
$t = "before"
1..2 | Tee-Object -Variable t
```

So why is it that the next code snippet has `$t` equal to `"before"` instead of `@(1)`*?

```
$t = "before"
1..2 | Tee-Object -Variable t | Select-Object -First 1
```

I see the same result in Powershell version 5 and version 3.

Answer (score 9):

This has to do with how the pipeline works. If you use a different cmdlet, like `Write-Verbose` it will work as expected:

```
$t = "before"
1..2 | Tee-Object -Variable t | Write-Verbose -Verbose
```

Consider that during a pipeline, each function or cmdlet can use a `Begin`,`Process`, and `End` block.

All the `Begin` blocks run first, then `Process` is called once for each pipeline object, and then all the `End`s.

The variable assignment necessarily has to happen in the `End` block.

Starting in PowerShell v3, cmdlets can interrupt the pipeline.

This is great for something like `Select-Object -First 1` because it means the entire pipeline can be stopped after the first object, instead of executing once for each item even though the rest will be discarded.

But it also means that the `End` block never runs.

If you start powershell in v2: `powershell.exe -Version 2.0`

And then run your second example, it will work as expected because the pipeline couldn't be prematurely stopped in that version.

---

Here's a demonstration:

```
function F1 {
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
    $o
)

    Begin {
        Write-Verbose "Begin" -Verbose
    }

    Process {
        Write-Verbose $o -Verbose
        $o
    }

    End {
        Write-Verbose "End" -Verbose
    }
}
```

Then call it:

```
1..2 | F1
```

vs.

```
1..2 | F1 | Select-Object -First 1
```

You could also demonstrate this with `ForEach-Object`:

```
1..2 | ForEach-Object -Begin {
    Write-Verbose "Begin" -Verbose
} -Process {
    Write-Verbose $_ -Verbose
    $_
} -End {
    Write-Verbose "End" -Verbose
}
```

vs.

```
1..2 | ForEach-Object -Begin {
    Write-Verbose "Begin" -Verbose
} -Process {
    Write-Verbose $_ -Verbose
    $_
} -End {
    Write-Verbose "End" -Verbose
} | Select-Object -First 1
```

---

According to [the documentation you linked](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849895.aspx), you can use the `-Wait` parameter to turn off this optimization:

```
$t = "before"
1..2 | Tee-Object -Variable t | Select-Object -First 1 -Wait
```

This will populate `$t` but perhaps not with the value you wanted. It will contain `@(1,2)`, presumably since the `-OutVariable` was placed on `Tee-Object` and not on `Select-Object`.

Remember that the "result" of the pipeline is what gets returned from the execution (left side of the `=`), and that is correct in all instances.

`-OutVariable` is something implemented by some cmdlets, and it most likely has to be implemented in the `End` block for that particular cmdlet, so to predict what it will give is highly dependent on understanding the execution flow of the pipeline.

So to answer the question in your comment, it appears to me to be implemented correctly. Am I misunderstanding your assertion?

Comment: Regarding specifications of "Select-Object -First" (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849895.aspx) and "Tee-Object -Variable" (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849937.aspx) Powershell 3+ pipeline optimization is implemented incorrectly. Correct implementation should give result @(1) - stream broken after first element or @(1,2) - untouched stream. Do you agree?

Comment: Forced order of evaluation (effectively splitting the pipeline in two) with parentheses is another option: `(1..2|tee -variable t) |select -first 1`